# angular filter on object works but causes Infinite $digest Loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I gave an object as followed

```
{
    key1: [{...}, {...} ....],
    key2: [{...}, {...} ....],
    .........so on .....
}
```

I have an ng-repeat `ng-repeat="(key, values) in data"` and then inside that `ng-repeat="val in values"`

I want to set up an filter based on some property of objects stored in the array. I have set up below filter

```
.filter('objFilter', function () {
                return function (input, search,field) {
                    if (!input || !search || !field)
                        return input;
                    var expected = ('' + search).toLowerCase();
                    var result = {};
                    angular.forEach(input, function (value, key) {
                        result[key] = [];
                        if(value && value.length !== undefined){
                            for(var i=0; i<value.length;i++){
                                var ip = value[i];
                                var actual = ('' + ip[field]).toLowerCase();
                                if (actual.indexOf(expected) !== -1) {
                                    result[key].push(value[i]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    console.log(result);
                    return result;
                };
```

The filter seems to work fine when I use `ng-repeat="(date, values) in data| objFilter:search:'url'"` but for some reason it is called too many times and causes Infinite $digest Loop.
Any solutions??

Edit:
I have created below plunker to show the issue. The filter works but look in the console for the errors. http://plnkr.co/edit/BXyi75kXT5gkK4E3F5PI

Comment: Please provide a fiddle with some dummy data so we can debug.

Comment: I have updated the question with a plunker to show the issue

Answer (score 2):

Your filter causes an infinite $digest loop because it always returns a new object instance. With the same parameters it returns a new object instance (*it doesn't matter if the data inside the object is the same as before*).

Something causes a second digest phase. I'm guessing it's the nested ng-repeat. Angular calls filters on every digest phase and because you filter returns a new value it causes the framework to reevaluate the whole outer ng-repeat block which causes the same on the inner ng-repeat block.

### Option 1 - modify the filter

One fix you can do is to "stabilize" the filter. If it's called 2 times in a row with the same value it should return the same result.

Replace your filter with the following code:

```
app.filter('objFilter', function () {
    var lastSearch = null;
    var lastField = null;
    var lastResult = null;

    return function (input, search, field) {
        if (!input || !search || !field) {
            return input;
        }

        if (search == lastSearch && field == lastField) {
            return lastResult;
        }

        var expected = ('' + search).toLowerCase();
        var result = {};

        angular.forEach(input, function (value, key) {
            result[key] = [];
            if(value && value.length !== undefined){
                for(var i=0; i<value.length;i++){
                    var ip = value[i];
                    var actual = ('' + ip[field]).toLowerCase();
                    if (actual.indexOf(expected) !== -1) {
                        //if(result[key]){
                        result[key].push(value[i]);
                        //}else{
                        //    result[key] = [value[i]];
                        //}
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Cache params and last result
        lastSearch = search;
        lastField = field;
        lastResult = result;

        return result;
    };
});
```

This code will work but it's bad and prone to errors. It might also cause memory leaks by keeping the last provided arguments in memory.

## Option 2 - move the filter on model change

Better approach will be to remember the updated filtered data on model change. Keep you JavaScript as is. Change only the html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-if="data">
    Search: 
    <input type="text"  
           ng-model="search" 
           ng-init="filteredData = (data | objFilter:search:'url')"
           ng-change="filteredData = (data | objFilter:search:'url')">

    <div ng-repeat="(date, values) in filteredData">
      <div style="margin-top:30px;">{{date}}</div>
      <hr/>
      <div ng-repeat="val in values" class="item">
        <div class="h-url">{{val.url}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

First we add a wrapper `ng-if` with a requirement that `data` must have a value. This will ensure that our `ng-init` will have "data" in order to set the initial `filteredData` value.

We also change the outer ng-repeat to use `filteredData` instead of `data`. Then we update filtered data on the model change with the `ng-change` directive.

- `ng-init` will fire once after `data` value is set
- `ng-change` will be executed only when the user changes the input value

Now, no matter how many consecutive $digest phases you'll have, the filter won't fire again. It's attached on initialization (`ng-init`) and on user interaction (`ng-change`).

### Notes

Filters fire on every digest phase. As a general rule try avoiding attaching complex filters directly on ng-repeat.

- Every user interaction with a field that has ng-model causes a $digest phase
- Every call of **$timeout** causes a $digest phase (*by default*).
- Every time you load something with **$http** a digest phase will begin.

All those will cause the ng-repeat with attached filter to reevaluate, thus resulting in child scopes creation/destruction and DOM elements manipulations which is heavy. It might not lead to infinite $digest loop but will kill your app performance.

Comment: I thought of going with the second approach. This works but I get my `data` with an $http and by the time it loads data, ng-init is already initialized hence shows an empty list. But right after I search something it works because the filter is evaluated. Any idea how I can run the filter after I load data?

Comment: Also this will not update my mg-repeat when I change my data.

Comment: It should't show an empty list. In my example there is an ng-if="data" on a parent element. Ng-init won't be executed before data has a non null value. Try it.

Comment: Also, if you need to update data and get filteredData synced consider making your filter a service and then calling it from the controller when there is an update condition. This is what I would do. Your code is getting too compex for a filter.

Comment: I tried this `$scope.filteredHistory = $filter('objFilter')($scope.data,$scope.search,'url')` when ever I am changing `data` but for some reason it doesn't update the view. Putting `$scope.filteredHistory` in console shows the result tough.

Comment: Isn' t the variable named filteredData? In the code you posted it's named filteredHistory. If that's not the case then how are you loading the data? Are you using $http?

Comment: Are you keeping the filter usage in the html? The Ng-if there is creating a child scope. Because you set the value from the controller remove ng-if="data" and the ng-init. Keep only the ng-change.

Comment: + 1 for option 2. I had been scouring SO and google for hours with an infinite digest loop issue on a custom filter that did data ordering. It was resolved by filtering the data on ng-click instead of filtering on the ng-repeat. Sold work, my friend